# No tests found only happens on Android 10

Tags: android-studio, automated-tests, android-espresso

When trying to run tests on Android phones running Android 10 I get the error "No Tests Were Found". This only happens on Android 10 phones. If any other OS, the espresso tests run just fine. 
I've tried invalidating caches/restarting. I'm running instrumentation tests, not unit tests. I'm using Junit 4.12 and running on Android Studio 3.5.3.

Any other ideas as to why this is happening on Android 10 only?

```
defaultConfig {
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And the logcat:

```
2020-02-20 11:43:18.924 8782-9279/? E/EPDG -- SIM0 [RILRECEIVER]: RX [NET_REGIST] -- RESPONSE -- not initialized
2020-02-20 11:43:18.939 8782-9279/? E/EPDG -- SIM0 [RILRECEIVER]: RX [NET_REGIST] -- RESPONSE -- not initialized
2020-02-20 11:43:19.034 6051-6051/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-02-20 11:43:19.037 6051-6051/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-02-20 11:43:19.064 6051-6051/? E/app.telephonyu: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-02-20 11:43:19.210 6051-6075/? E/ServiceBindHelper: time out 25, com.samsung.telephony.phone.service.internalservice.ISamsungInternalService$Stub$Proxy@bf281f
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217003.353:102559): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=6082 comm="installer" name="nativetest" dev="sda31" ino=641 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:nativetest_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1582217003.353:102559): arch=c00000b7 syscall=48 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=7fd6784e01 a2=4 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6080 pid=6082 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 tty=pts3 ses=4294967295 comm="installer" exe="/data/local/tmp/.studio/bin/installer" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1582217003.353:102559): proctitle=2F646174612F6C6F63616C2F746D702F2E73747564696F2F62696E2F696E7374616C6C6572002D76657273696F6E3D61373331326436610064756D7000636F6D2E7370696E6361722E7370696E636172616E64726F69642E6465627567
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217003.353:102560): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=6082 comm="installer" name="nativetest64" dev="sda31" ino=644 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:nativetest_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1582217003.353:102560): arch=c00000b7 syscall=48 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=7fd6784e01 a2=4 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6080 pid=6082 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 tty=pts3 ses=4294967295 comm="installer" exe="/data/local/tmp/.studio/bin/installer" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
2020-02-20 11:43:23.364 738-738/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1582217003.353:102560): proctitle=2F646174612F6C6F63616C2F746D702F2E73747564696F2F62696E2F696E7374616C6C6572002D76657273696F6E3D61373331326436610064756D7000636F6D2E7370696E6361722E7370696E636172616E64726F69642E6465627567
2020-02-20 11:43:24.682 4012-4012/? E/Finsky: [2] aagy.b(2): Package name null is not an installed package
2020-02-20 11:43:25.980 1040-5452/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl89474560.tmp: No such file or directory
2020-02-20 11:43:26.052 1305-1305/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.spincar.spincarandroid.debug'!
2020-02-20 11:43:26.071 8511-8511/? E/Telephony: PhoneUtils: getPhoneFromIccId - phone is null
2020-02-20 11:43:26.071 8511-8511/? E/VVM.VvmPkgInstalledRcvr: cannot create TelephonyManager from ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0}
2020-02-20 11:43:26.073 1305-1305/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider.INTENT_PACKAGE_REMOVED from system uid 1000 pkg com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16942)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17707)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17889)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17865)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:20751)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:493)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:296)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:288)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6627)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.sendAndReturnResult(PendingIntent.java:946)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:917)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:825)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.sendIntentAction(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:439)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.access$600(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:70)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService$UnionContentBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:264)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:929)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:723)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.076 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217006.063:102571): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=6129 comm="installer" name="nativetest" dev="sda31" ino=641 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:nativetest_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:26.076 738-738/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1582217006.063:102571): arch=c00000b7 syscall=48 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=7fd7b98e21 a2=4 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6125 pid=6129 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 tty=pts2 ses=4294967295 comm="installer" exe="/data/local/tmp/.studio/bin/installer" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.076 738-738/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1582217006.063:102571): proctitle=2F646174612F6C6F63616C2F746D702F2E73747564696F2F62696E2F696E7374616C6C6572002D76657273696F6E3D61373331326436610064756D7000636F6D2E7370696E6361722E7370696E636172616E64726F69642E64656275672E7465737400636F6D2E7370696E6361722E7370696E636172616E64726F69642E6465
2020-02-20 11:43:26.076 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217006.063:102572): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=6129 comm="installer" name="nativetest64" dev="sda31" ino=644 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:nativetest_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:26.129 1305-1305/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast action_package_removed from system uid 1000 pkg com.android.settings
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16942)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17707)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17889)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17865)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:20751)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:493)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:296)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:288)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6627)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.sendAndReturnResult(PendingIntent.java:946)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:917)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:825)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.sendIntentAction(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:439)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.access$600(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:70)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService$UnionContentBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:264)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:929)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:723)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.139 1305-1305/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.spincar.spincarandroid.debug'!
2020-02-20 11:43:26.159 6146-6146/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-02-20 11:43:26.159 6146-6146/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-02-20 11:43:26.167 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2020-02-20 11:43:26.168 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2020-02-20 11:43:26.171 6146-6146/? E/pp.galaxyfinde: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-02-20 11:43:26.255 8511-8511/? E/Telephony: PhoneUtils: getPhoneFromIccId - phone is null
2020-02-20 11:43:26.255 8511-8511/? E/VVM.VvmPkgInstalledRcvr: cannot create TelephonyManager from ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0}
2020-02-20 11:43:26.260 1305-1305/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider.INTENT_PACKAGE_ADDED from system uid 1000 pkg com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16942)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17707)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17889)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17865)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:20751)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:493)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:296)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:288)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6627)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.sendAndReturnResult(PendingIntent.java:946)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:917)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:825)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.sendIntentAction(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:439)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.access$600(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:70)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService$UnionContentBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:264)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:929)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:723)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.429 1305-1305/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast action_package_added from system uid 1000 pkg com.android.settings
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16942)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17707)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17889)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17865)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:20751)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:493)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:296)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:288)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6627)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.sendAndReturnResult(PendingIntent.java:946)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:917)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:825)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.sendIntentAction(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:439)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.access$600(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:70)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService$UnionContentBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:264)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:929)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:723)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.473 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2020-02-20 11:43:26.581 6200-6200/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: android.support.test.orchestrator
2020-02-20 11:43:26.653 6200-6200/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: android.support.test.orchestrator
2020-02-20 11:43:26.654 1305-1305/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast action_package_replaced from system uid 1000 pkg com.android.settings
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16942)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17707)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17889)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:17865)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:20751)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:493)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:296)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendWithResult(PendingIntentRecord.java:288)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.sendIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6627)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.sendAndReturnResult(PendingIntent.java:946)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:917)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:825)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.sendIntentAction(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:439)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService.access$600(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:70)
        at com.android.server.sepunion.SemDeviceInfoManagerService$UnionContentBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SemDeviceInfoManagerService.java:264)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:929)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:723)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
2020-02-20 11:43:26.666 6146-6214/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.service.tagservice
2020-02-20 11:43:26.714 6146-6224/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.service.tagservice
2020-02-20 11:43:26.774 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2020-02-20 11:43:26.849 6243-6243/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: android.support.test.services
2020-02-20 11:43:26.855 6246-6246/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-02-20 11:43:26.855 6246-6246/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-02-20 11:43:26.868 6246-6246/? E/ACMS.Process: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-02-20 11:43:26.927 5104-5104/? E/FilterIntentReceiver: This package is not a effect filter
2020-02-20 11:43:26.951 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2020-02-20 11:43:26.962 5193-5218/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mlwhitelist
2020-02-20 11:43:26.984 1305-8613/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.samsung.android.intent.action.RESPONSE_SERVICEBOX_REMOTEVIEWS from system 5043:com.samsung.android.app.routines:RoutineUIProcess/u0a10 pkg com.samsung.android.app.routines
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:16938)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17611)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:16956)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:17849)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2281)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3312)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
2020-02-20 11:43:27.001 8558-8558/? E/SystemUIImageView: set Image Drawable!!
2020-02-20 11:43:27.001 8558-8558/? E/SystemUIImageView: set Background Drawable!!
2020-02-20 11:43:27.002 8558-8558/? E/SystemUIImageView: set Image Drawable!!
2020-02-20 11:43:27.003 8558-8558/? E/SystemUIImageView: set Image Drawable!!
2020-02-20 11:43:27.003 8558-8558/? E/SystemUIImageView: set Background Drawable!!
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 6284-6284/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.zit.enable"
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 6284-6284/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.zit.try"
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217007.233:102589): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6284 comm="main" name="u:object_r:vendor_zygoteinit_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=26914 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_zygoteinit_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 738-738/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1582217007.233:102589): arch=c00000b7 syscall=56 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=7feeb90150 a2=88000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6278 pid=6284 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 tty=pts2 ses=4294967295 comm="main" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:shell:s0 key=(null)
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 738-738/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1582217007.233:102589): proctitle=6170705F70726F63657373002F00616E64726F69642E737570706F72742E746573742E73657276696365732E7368656C6C6578656375746F722E5368656C6C4D61696E00616D00696E737472756D656E74002D72002D77002D6500746172676574496E737472756D656E746174696F6E00636F6D2E7370696E6361722E737069
2020-02-20 11:43:27.242 738-738/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1582217007.233:102590): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6284 comm="main" name="u:object_r:vendor_zygoteinit_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=26914 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_zygoteinit_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G973U1_10_0005 audit_filtered
2020-02-20 11:43:27.243 6284-6284/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: registerfunction enter
2020-02-20 11:43:27.268 6284-6284/? E/ToolConnection: Connecting to content providers has failed!
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.app.IActivityManager.getContentProviderExternal [class java.lang.String, int, interface android.os.IBinder]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection$ToolConnectionPostIcs.doCall(ToolConnection.java:131)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:79)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:69)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.BlockingPublish.getResult(BlockingPublish.java:74)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellCommandExecutorServer.start(ShellCommandExecutorServer.java:80)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:40)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:339)
2020-02-20 11:43:27.277 6284-6284/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 6284
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.app.IActivityManager.getContentProviderExternal [class java.lang.String, int, interface android.os.IBinder]
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection$ToolConnectionPostIcs.doCall(ToolConnection.java:185)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:79)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:69)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.BlockingPublish.getResult(BlockingPublish.java:74)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellCommandExecutorServer.start(ShellCommandExecutorServer.java:80)
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:40)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:339)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.app.IActivityManager.getContentProviderExternal [class java.lang.String, int, interface android.os.IBinder]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection$ToolConnectionPostIcs.doCall(ToolConnection.java:131)
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:79) 
        at android.support.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:69) 
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.BlockingPublish.getResult(BlockingPublish.java:74) 
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellCommandExecutorServer.start(ShellCommandExecutorServer.java:80) 
        at android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:40) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:339) 
2020-02-20 11:43:27.278 6284-6284/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad file descriptor
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:526)
        at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService(ServiceManagerNative.java:128)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.rawGetService(ServiceManager.java:272)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityManager$1.create(ActivityManager.java:4545)
        at android.app.ActivityManager$1.create(ActivityManager.java:4542)
        at android.util.Singleton.get(Singleton.java:38)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.getService(ActivityManager.java:4533)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:146)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2187)
2020-02-20 11:43:27.410 8511-8511/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager:
```

Comment: I am in trouble because the same issue has occurred. However, using Android X's Test library does not cause any problems.

Comment: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/450

Comment: It is said that it has been modified in version 1.2.0. To use version 1.2.0 you need to migrate to Android X.

Comment: If it is resolved through the Android Support Library, please comment.

Comment: Yes, it appears that migrating to AndroidX does fix this issue. Thank you!